# BindingResult does not work, thymeleaf can't see it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this method

```
    @PostMapping
public String saveOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute OrderCreationDto order,
                        BindingResult bindingResult,
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                        Model model) {
    System.out.println("BINDING " + bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        fillMenuModelWithData(model);
        return "menu";
    }


    try {
        orderService.saveOrder(order, authenticatedUser);
    } catch (InsufficientFundsException e) {
        log.debug(e.toString());
        fillMenuModelWithData(model);
        return "menu";
    }
    return "redirect:/orders/history";
}
```

And this helper method just to fill models with needed attributes

```
    private void fillMenuModelWithData(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("sortField", DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD);
    model.addAttribute("sortDir", DEFAULT_SORT_DIR);
    model.addAttribute("filterCategory", DEFAULT_CATEGRY);
    model.addAttribute("pageSize", DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    model.addAttribute("filterCategory", DEFAULT_CATEGRY);
    model.addAttribute("order", new OrderCreationDto());
    model.addAttribute("dishList", dishService.findAllDishesSorted(
            DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD, DEFAULT_SORT_DIR));
}
```

As you can see, I print to console with `System.out.println` my BindingResult and it looks like this.

> BINDING org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2
> errors

> Field error in object 'orderCreationDto' on field 'address':
> rejected value [ ]; codes
> [NotBlank.orderCreationDto.address,NotBlank.address,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [orderCreationDto.address,address]; arguments []; default
> message [address]]; default message [Address cannot be empty]
>
> Field error in object 'orderCreationDto' on field 'dishIdQuantityMap':
> rejected value [{752=0, 952=0}]; codes
> [HasOrder.orderCreationDto.dishIdQuantityMap,HasOrder.dishIdQuantityMap,HasOrder.java.util.Map,HasOrder];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [orderCreationDto.dishIdQuantityMap,dishIdQuantityMap];
> arguments []; default message [dishIdQuantityMap]]; default message
> [Order does not contain any Dishes]

Seems like everything ok, let's see if we have any erros on `menu` page.

```
               <p th:text="${#fields.errors()}"></p>
            <p th:text="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}"></p>
```

And we see nothing

[image]

I've tried to debug this on my own for the whole night, need your help a lot!

UPD:

Here is the error I get skip adding new Order in Post method

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'order' available as request attribute
```

Comment: you probably loose your modal values on redirect. I don't remember exactly how it is in thymleaf but I am guessing it doesnt persist between requests

Comment: Don't add the `order` to the model, it is already part of it.

Comment: @JAsgarov the problem is that I am not redirecting, I trigger my bindingresults to fail with an empty field and it just does what is stated in the first if - returns the page filled with modal attributes.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, it seems like this has something to do with adding new Order. The problem is that I have a form with `th:object="${order}"` and it gives me an exception 
` Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'order' available as request attribute`
If I don't add it

Comment: @M.Deinum the exception was fixed. God bless you!

Comment: Due to the binding it is added automatically, you are replacing it with a new version which then invalidates the binding results as that was for a different object instance.

Answer (score 0):

The very same problem bothered me for a while and the solution is within the comments. So I'd like to highlight it as an explicit fix.

User [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139586/bindingresult-does-not-work-thymeleaf-cant-see-it#comment125753552_71139586):

> Don't add the order to the model, it is already part of it

and

> Due to the binding it is added automatically, you are replacing it with a new version which then invalidates the binding results as that was for a different object instance

In my case I initialize a couple of model attributes and wrote a method to do this for both the `Get-` and the `PostMapping`. I did not realize that in the `Post` case it overrides the already given model attribute.

Thanks to the eyes of an experienced Spring user!